# Java pattern matching from a log

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have a log which looks something like this. I want to extract only **id** and **compartmentId** i.e
"ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaacbo75pldukgsvt6a54jxws4ywrh4gh5nnflykzfuajxicuym7pla" and "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaxnzexdpskbmudhtcfya4qtoyz5qzvwjqz56sjregusdxhopuyd3a"
it can have many occurance and can have different values but prefix will either be "ocid1.compartment.oc1" or "ocid1.tenancy.oc1"

below is the log example----

```
Compartment(id=ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaacbo75pldukgsvt6a54jxws4ywrh4gh5nnflykzfuajxicuym7pla, compartmentId=ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaxnzexdpskbmudhtcfya4qtoyz5qzvwjqz56sjregusdxhopuyd3a, name=cdr-sandbox.kzJ7ZeWt, description=....CreatedOn=2020-05-26T17:43:32.343Z}}, __explicitlySet__=[compartmentId, lifecycleState, name, description, timeCreated, id, definedTags, freeformTags])
Compartment(id=ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaaymeyk2zu5iodrhwnhhgcw5ory7vozx6ozhoxveowik767wv5zfaq, compartmentId=ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaxnzexdpskbmudhtcfya4qtoyz5qzvwjqz56sjregusdxhopuyd3a, name=cp-1.wbTRj4co, description=CP-1, timeCreated=Thu Jul 30 13:06:12 IST 2020, lifecycleState=Deleted, inactiveStatus=null, isAccessible=null, freeformTags={}, CreatedOn=2020-07-30T07:36:12.218Z}}, __explicitlySet__=[compartmentId, lifecycleState, name, description, timeCreated, id, definedTags, freeformTags])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `String#replaceAll` for a one-liner option:

```
String log = "Compartment(id=ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaacbo75pldukgsvt6a54jxws4ywrh4gh5nnflykzfuajxicuym7pla, compartmentId=ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaxnzexdpskbmudhtcfya4qtoyz5qzvwjqz56sjregusdxhopuyd3a, name=cdr-sandbox.kzJ7ZeWt, description=....CreatedOn=2020-05-26T17:43:32.343Z}}, __explicitlySet__=[compartmentId, lifecycleState, name, description, timeCreated, id, definedTags, freeformTags])";
String id = log.replaceAll(".*\\bid=([^,]+).*", "$1");
String compartmentId = log.replaceAll(".*\\bcompartmentId=([^,]+).*", "$1");
System.out.println("id = " + id);
System.out.println("compartmentId = " + compartmentId);
```

This prints:

```
id = ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaacbo75pldukgsvt6a54jxws4ywrh4gh5nnflykzfuajxicuym7pla
compartmentId = ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaaxnzexdpskbmudhtcfya4qtoyz5qzvwjqz56sjregusdxhopuyd3a
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, it works. Is there a way to remove the duplicate occurrence of id and compartmentID, as log have multiple entry of same id and compartmentID

Comment: Honestly, this new requirement sounds maybe like something you should handle within your logging framework.